# Sequelize - How to access joining table in M:M

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize, HAPI and MySQL.

I have the two models, that have M:M via linking table that is automatically created.

This is how I make M:M:

```
Project.belongsToMany(models.ProjectTag, {through: 'ProjectToProjectTags'});
ProjectTag.belongsToMany(models.Project, {through: 'ProjectToProjectTags'});
```

That statement makes the third table called ProjectToProjectTags.

Now when I want to create a tag, and assign it to a project, I try the following code:

```
newTag.TagName = request.payload.tagname;
    newTag.TagDescription = request.payload.tagdescription;

    models.ProjectTag.create(newTag).then(function (newTagCreated) {
        var newTagToProject = {};
        newTagToProject.ProjectTagId = newTagCreated.id;
        newTagToProject.ProjectId = ProjectId;
        models.ProjectToProjectTag.create(newTagToProject).then(function
        (newTagCreated) {
            response(newTagCreated).code(200);
        })
    })
```

Code fails at the second create line:

```
models.ProjectToProjectTag.create
```

Table **ProjectToProjectTag** model does not exist, since it was automatically created. How can I do this update?

Answer (score 0):

You say it creates the Model `ProjectToProjectTags`, but you use `ProjectToProjectTag`. Guess you should just change it to `ProjectToProjectTags` (plural).

So

```
models.ProjectToProjectTags.create
```

instead of

```
models.ProjectToProjectTag.create
```

Comment: Yes, that is mistake in the code. However, the table ProjectToProjectTags is created, but there is no model having such name. I would like to avoid raw query if possible.

Comment: Do you actually have a file containing the model `ProjectToProjectTags`  ? Cause I guess the table `ProjectToProjectTags` is created, but there is no actual Model. See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#nm

Comment: I dont have the actual file. Do I need it? If yes, then what should I put in it?

Comment: Check out the link: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#nm They show an example with models `Post`, `Tag` and `ItemTag` (representing the join-table)

Comment: That post led me to solution. Thanks :)